# The non-asymptotically stability of $\frac{dx}{dt}=y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=-g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For an autonomous differential equations with two unknows i.e.:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=-g(x)
\end{equation}
Suggest $g(x)$ is countinous and $xg(x)>0$ when $x\neq0$.
I would like to proof the zero soulution but not asymptotically stable and my ideas so far:

It's easy to show $g(x)>0 $ when $x>0$ and $g(x)<0$ when $x<0$. And by the continous of $g(x)$, we have $g(0)=0.$ So $(0,0)$ is the solution of $y=0, -g(x)=0.$

By using a lyapunov function $V(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}y^2+\int_{0}^{x}g(s)ds$. To proof $V>0$, I used mean value theorem, where $V(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}y^2+xg(\xi)>0$, $\xi\in(0,x)$ or $(x,0)$.

Aslo, We have $\frac{dV}{dt}=yy'+g(x)x'=y(-g(x))+g(x)y=0$. This means zero soulutiohn is stable. But can I say the zero solution $(0,0)$ is not asymptotically stable just by $\frac{dV}{dt}$=0? Since the derivative is always $0$, so any integral curve near $(0,0)$ cannot drop down to $(0,0)$. Is my proof right? Or I need some more evidences to derive the non-asymptotically stability?

Comment: $xg(\xi) > 0$ is not correct, since $x \neq \xi$ in general. By the way, this is not enough evidence I would suppose.

Comment: It is correct, since $\xi\in(0,x)$ or $(x,0)$, It doesn't need '$x=\xi$'

Comment: No. The condition is $xg(x)>0$, not $xg(\xi)>0$. Yes, the MVT is applicable but wat you say about the sign is wrong.

Comment: From $xg(x)>0$，we know $g(x)>0$ when $x>0$, $g(x)<0$ when $x<0$, then we known $xg(\xi)>0$ since $\xi \in(x,0)$ or $(0,x)$. Specially, $\xi$ has the same sign with $x$, so when $x>0$, we have $\xi>0$, so $g(\xi)>0$, so $xg(\xi)>0$. When $x<0$, this also holds. Please check it again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess you are right. My mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should be it: Assume that there is some $r>0$ such that for every solution $(x(t), y(t))$ with initial datum in $B_r(0)\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} (x(t), y(t)) = 0$.

Continuity would mean that $\displaystyle\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} V(x(t), y(t)) = 0$. But since $V(x(t), y(t))$ is constant, we must have $V(x(t), y(t)) = V(x(0), y(0)) \neq 0$, since the initial datum $(x(0), y(0))$ was assumed to be non-zero.

So your intuition was correct.